# Prolog reversible arithmetic

Tags: math, prolog

Is there any way in prolog to ask questions like `4 is 2^X`, and then get back `X=2`? I've tried to use `=`, `==`, `=:=` all without success (getting either just `false` or `arguments not sufficiently instantiated`).

Comment: It seems like this might be the real question you were asking in your recent, similar question. Perhaps delete the other, unless it yielded some useful answers?

Comment: I realize that now, I'm sorry for sort of double-posting! There was some really good answers in that one too, though...

Answer (score 7):

With SWI-Prolog and the library(clpfd) you can ask question like that.

```
 ?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
%  library(apply_macros) compiled into apply_macros 0,00 sec, 39 clauses
%  library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0,03 sec, 143 clauses
% library(clpfd) compiled into clpfd 0,11 sec, 1,456 clauses
true.

 ?- 4 #= 2 * X.
X = 2.
```

Comment: I can't use libraries for this particual program :/

Comment: I would say that CLP(R) is more appropriate, or at least advise that this will work only for integers

Comment: @fafner: just out of curiosity, why do accept you this anwwer if it can't help with your actual problem ?

Comment: Oops, didn't know I had... Sorry, I've been up all night

Comment: @false: I guess there is some Prolog out there where use_module(...) vs [...] make a difference. Apart for the ability to restrict the imported symbols, it's hard to spot any difference... It's an ISO requirement ?

Comment: @CapelliC: That works in SWI only and I doubt that it has any semantics safe the coincidental it happens to have.

Comment: @false: I tested YAP also, with success. But I guess this is due to the fact that Jan and Vitor seem willing to collaborate promoting convergence of their systems...

Comment: @CapelliC: You did not test YAP very thoroughly. Simply typing `[library(clpfd)]` twice at the toplevel produces a fatal error...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith) to generate integers:

```
?- between(1,1000,Y), X is 2 ^ Y, X == 4.
Y = 2,
X = 4 ;
false.

?- between(1,1000,Y), X is 2 ^ Y, X == 32.
Y = 5,
X = 32 ;
false.
```

You can also use `inf` for the second argument of `between/3`, but without some limiting condition that will cause these queries to loop after they give their first answer. ([`numlist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists), is another option, in case you find it makes more sense to work with lists of numbers instead of generating a new number each time it backtracks).

Writing a general purpose predicate for this might look like,

```
within_range(Low-High, X=Operation) :-
    between(Low, High, V1),
    between(Low, High, V2),
    Operation =.. [_, V1, V2],
    Y is Operation,
    Y = X.
```

Of course, this only works with 2 place operations without considerable tweaking. Some example queries:

```
?- within_range(1-100, 8=X*Y).
X = 1,
Y = 8 ;
X = 2,
Y = 4 ;
X = 4,
Y = 2 ;
X = 8,
Y = 1 ;
false.

?- within_range(1-100, 8=14-X).
X = 6 ;
false.
```

Comment: I should note, joel76's answer advising use of the `library(clpfd)` is the correct and now standard answer for this in SWI-Prolog. However, my answer is still a viable and simple approach for this problem when external libraries cannot be used for some reason.  CapelliC's answer branching on the mode of the variables supplied is a smarter and more efficient approach, but not as  pleasing from a declarative perspective.

Answer (score 2):

you can check *instantiation status* of a variable

```
% E is X^Y
% here are accepted patterns
%
% exp(+,+,-)
% exp(-,+,+)
% exp(+,-,+)
%
exp(X,Y,E) :-
     var(E)
  -> E is X^Y % note: will throw an error if either X or Y are not bound to number
  ;  var(X)
  -> compute_base_of_exp_here(Y,E,X) % note: as above, with E in place of X
  ;  var(Y)
  -> (   X =:= e % we are lucky, only natural logarithms are available as ISO builtin
      -> Y is log(X)
      ;  X =:= 2 % again, we could be lucky, log2 can be rather easy to compute...
      -> compute_log2_here(E,Y)
      ;  compute_some_complex_math_here(X,E,Y)
     )
   ; E is X^Y . % no vars?
```

but this is going to be a rather difficult route, without appropriate builtins...

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to have asked the same question before, the short answer:

No, you cannot ask this question like this.

You would have to implement this yourself. The `library(clpfd)` mentioned does pretty much what you need. At the least, you can try and look at the implementation for inspiration.

Comment: Also looking at the expanded source is inspiring :)